# How to print multiple stanza (user) using the lssec command in AIX

Tags: aix

The 'lssec' command lists the attributes from security stanza files.

My aim is to fetch an attribute (for example - admin) from the file '/etc/security/user' for each stanza(users).

The command works like this:

```
lssec -f /etc/security/user -s user1 -a admin
```

The above command list the 'admin' attribute for 'user1' stanza.

Now the difficulty is that this command is not taking multiple values for stanza like -

```
lssec -f /etc/security/user -s user1, user2, user3 -a admin
```

The above command gives error.

Now I want to do this for each stanza (user1, user2, user3) in a single command. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As per IBM documentation you can specify only one user in to the user stanza field. Please check [official page here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/l_commands/lssec.html)